# Could not find method destination() for arguments on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.findbugs.FindBugsXmlReportImpl

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating the android studio version to 3.4.0 I updated the Gradle version to 5.1.1 and tried rebuilding the project it is throwing an exception in quality.gradle file.

```
 Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/Desktop/workplace/testProject/quality/quality.gradle' line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find method destination() for arguments [/home/Desktop/workplace/testProject/app/build/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml] on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.findbugs.FindBugsXmlReportImpl.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**Android Project Level classpath URL and Gradle distribution URL**

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

I tried doing invalidate the cache and restart the project. it keeps failing

**Here is my quality.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/quality/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    configProperties = [
            'checkstyle.cache.file': rootProject.file('build/checkstyle.cache'),
            'checkstyleSuppressionsPath': file("${project.rootDir}/quality/checkstyle/suppressions.xml").absolutePath
    ]
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    exclude '**/commons/**' //exclude copied stuff from apache commons
    classpath = files()
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    excludeFilter file("${project.rootDir}/quality/findbugs/findbugs-filter.xml")
    classes = fileTree('build/intermediates/classes/')

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.html"
        }
    }

    classpath = files()
}

task pmd(type: Pmd) {
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSetFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/quality/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ruleSets = []

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/pmd/pmd.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/pmd/pmd.html"
        }
    }
}

check.doLast {
    project.tasks.getByName("checkstyle").execute()
    project.tasks.getByName("findbugs").execute()
    project.tasks.getByName("pmd").execute()
    project.tasks.getByName("lint").execute()
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion '6.17'    // set Checkstyle version here
}
```

This is happening when I use the Gradle version 5.1.1 and Gradle classpath version 3.4.0. Earlier I was using Gradle 4.10.1 and classpath version 3.3.2.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Gradle 5.x `setDestination(Object file)` has been removed instead
 you must use

```
setDestination(File file)
```

which takes a File parameter
so instead of

`destination "$yourpath"`

replace it with

```
destination file("$yourpath")
```

check [gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/ConfigurableReport.html#setDestination-java.io.File-)

Comment: Hi, @tamtom I made the changes it's working fine. But its throwing another error
 could not find method execute() for the lines     project.tasks.getByName("checkstyle").execute() in last section of quality.gradle()

Answer (score 11):

Proper example should be

```
 reports{
    html.enabled true
    html.destination(file("$yourpath"))
 }
 classpath = files()
```