# Generating code coverage reports on Azure DevOps with Gradle 5.X

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, jacoco

I'm trying to upgrade my project to Gradle 5.6.2. One of the tasks that I run on Azure DevOps is:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: 'Test Project'
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx7000m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: 2.6.2
    testRunTitle: $(DISPLAY_NAME)
    codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: "test -Dtest.profile=unit --parallel"
```

After upgrading to Gradle 5.6.2 I get the following error when the code coverage reports are run:

> Could not find method `destination()` for arguments [/home/vsts/work/1/s/batch/build/jacocoHtml] on Report html of type `org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskGeneratedSingleDirectoryReport`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55919067/2648), some changes were made to the reporting API in Gradle 5.X. Is the version of JaCoCo that's used on Azure Devops incompatible with Gradle 5.X? If so, is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: As per [answer that you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918239/could-not-find-method-destination-for-arguments-on-report-xml-of-type-org-grad/55919067#55919067) you have to change your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method destination() for arguments on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.findbugs.FindBugsXmlReportImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918239/could-not-find-method-destination-for-arguments-on-report-xml-of-type-org-grad)

Comment: Hi, how the thins going? Does modify your build.gradle file syntax could solve your issue? Feel free to leave comment here if you still facing any error.

Answer (score 4):

> Some changes were made to the reporting API in Gradle 5.X, Is the version of JaCoCo that's used on Azure Devops incompatible with Gradle 5.X?

See this pull request: [JaCoCo compatible with gradle 5.x](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/11321/files/f3a6ef8d801ca1c8627125e607249254e8489ede). Last month, we raised a pull request to improve our `Gradle` task script since the feature has changed in `Gradle 5.x`([see this changes](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/11321/files/f3a6ef8d801ca1c8627125e607249254e8489ede)):

[image]

Also, the PR has been merged successfully. In one word, now, for our `Gradle` task, the Jacoco version is compatible with `Gradle 5.x` which has upgrade the new syntax.

To solve your issue, I suggest you'd better follow the solution which in the link you shared in question, to ensure the script of your `build.gradle` file is similar as the below format:

```
    destination file("$xx/xxx/xx.xml")
```

Also, you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671249/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-destination-after-update-to-gradle-5-2-1).